# MongoDb c# 2.0 driver - how can i calculate count of aggregations on server?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, mongodb-csharp-2.0

When i ran  `dbCollection.Aggregate().Group(groupby).Match(query)` I haven't any extention method to get a count of records what was aggregated. But i can run `ToListAsync` and then get `Count()`. How can i receive a count of records ?
I have `MongoDb v 3.0.2` and `c# driver 2.0`

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to construct a result like what solr or elastic search returns with a "total count" as well as any filtered data. For this you should run separate queries if that is what you are really asking.

Comment: I want to get count of returned results without receiving these results

Comment: The "cursor" returned by aggregate does not presently support such a thing as a standard cursor from `.find()`. To get the aggregated result count it is best to do what you are doing, or if streaming a response then count as you go and add that result to the output stream.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add one more group with **$sum**

```
var result = await collection
        .Aggregate()
        .Group(groupby)
        .Match(query)
        .Group(new BsonDocument
        {
            { "_id", "_id" },
            {"count", new BsonDocument("$sum", 1)}
        })
        .FirstAsync();
        var count = result["count"].AsInt32;
```